# Datatype conversion using tdbrow of talend

Tags: java, oracle, type-conversion, talend, abstract-data-type

I really need your help,i was using tdbsp (stored proc) before but now i need to use tdbrow for performing an insert into one of the oracle tables as part of the job flow.

Some of the columns in the insert statement are integers & date which is what is causing the problem and throws an error like "invalid number" and other things etc.I am able to manage the string part of it,but the really hassle lies with INTEGER datatype,can anyone of you guide me if i am missing any of the required quotes for successful insertion?

I am getting the fileID as Integer and storing it in global variable of tjava row:

```
globalMap.put("CFILEID", input_row.FILEID);
```

Now i am using it in the TDBROW component:

FILEID,DIRIRD,LOADID is stored as

number
in ORACLE datatype and FILE_DATE is stored as

DATE
in ORACLE.How do i convert in the required format?

```
 insert into table_file

   (

 fileid, dirid, loadid, file_name, file_date,file_size, 

  )

values

   (" +"\""+

 

 ((Integer)globalMap.get("CFILEID")) +","+ //FILEID
 NULL+","+ (kept it null for testing purpose) //DIRID

 NULL+","+ ///LOADID

 ((String)globalMap.get("CFILE_NAME")) +","+//FILENAME

 to_date(i_file_date,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),//FILEDATE ?????

 NULL+","+ //FILESIZE

)
```

The ORACLE insert command looks as below:

```
values (file_seq.nextval,

    l_dirid,

    l_loadid,

    i_file_name,

    to_date(i_file_date,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),

    i_file_size)
```

How to handle this specifically for INTEGER & DATE datatype from JAVA to ORACLE?

Any help or inputs would be totally appreciated,thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible for you to use something like :
tFixedFlow -> tMap -> tDBOutput
In tFixedFlow, create a schema with fileid, dirid, loadid, file_name, file_date,file_size with the right data type. Pass your global variables as values in tFixedFlow.
Then in tMap you map all those fields to your DB schema.
Then insert into your DB, the mapping between java types and Oracle types would be no problem.